# Text Mining using Jaro-Winkler fuzzy matching in R

Tags: r, text-mining, levenshtein-distance, jaro-winkler

Im attempting to do some distance matching in R and am struggling to achieve a usable output.

I have a dataframe `terms` that contains 5 strings of text, along with a category for each string. I have a second dataframe `notes` that contains 10 poorly spelt words, along with a NoteID.

I want to be able to compare each of my 5 `terms` against each of my 10 `notes` using a distance algorithm to try to grab simple spelling errors. I have tried:

`near_match<- subset(notes, jarowinkler(notes$word, terms$word) >0.9)`

```
   NoteID    Note
5      e5 thought
10     e5   tough
```

and

`jarowinkler(notes$word, terms$word)`

`[1] 0.8000000 0.7777778 0.8266667 0.8833333 0.9714286 0.8000000 0.8000000 0.8266667 0.8833333 0.9500000`

The first instance is almost what I need, it just lacks the word from `terms` that has caused the match. The second returns 10 scores but I'm not sure if the algorithm checked each of the 5 `terms` against each of the 10 `notes` in turn and just returned the closest match (highest score) or not.

How can I alter the above to achieve my desired output if what I want is achievable using `jarowinkler()` or is there a better option?

I'm relatively new to R so appreciate any help in furthering my understanding how the algorithm generates the scores and what the approach to achieve my desired output would be.

example dataframes below

Thanks

```
> notes
   NoteID    word
1      a1     hit
2      b2     hot
3      c3   shirt
4      d4    than
5      e5 thought
6      a1     hat
7      b2     get
8      c3   shirt
9      d4    than
10     e5   tough

> terms
  Category   word
1        a    hot
2        b    got
3        a   shot
4        d   that
5        c though
```

Comment: The [stringdist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf) package can help with this stuff, if you find yourself doing this a lot.

Comment: Also the [fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin) package is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data.frames:

```
notes<-data.frame(NoteID=c("a1","b2","c3","d4","e5","a1","b2","c3","d4","e5"),
                  word=c("hit","hot","shirt","than","thought","hat","get","shirt","that","tough"))
terms<-data.frame(Category=c("a","b","c","d","e"),
                  word=c("hot","got","shot","that","though"))
```

Use `stringdistmatrix` (package `stringdist`) with method "jw" (jarowinkler)

```
library(stringdist)
dist<-stringdistmatrix(notes$word,terms$word,method = "jw")
row.names(dist)<-as.character(notes$word)
colnames(dist)<-as.character(terms$word)
```

Now you have all distances:

```
dist
              hot       got       shot       that     though
hit     0.2222222 0.4444444 0.27777778 0.27777778 0.50000000
hot     0.0000000 0.2222222 0.08333333 0.27777778 0.33333333
shirt   0.4888889 1.0000000 0.21666667 0.36666667 0.54444444
than    0.4722222 1.0000000 0.50000000 0.16666667 0.38888889
thought 0.3571429 0.5158730 0.40476190 0.40476190 0.04761905
hat     0.2222222 0.4444444 0.27777778 0.08333333 0.50000000
get     0.4444444 0.2222222 0.47222222 0.47222222 0.50000000
shirt   0.4888889 1.0000000 0.21666667 0.36666667 0.54444444
that    0.2777778 0.4722222 0.33333333 0.00000000 0.38888889
tough   0.4888889 0.4888889 0.51666667 0.51666667 0.05555556
```

Find the word more close to notes

```
output<-cbind(notes,word_close=terms[as.numeric(apply(dist, 1, which.min)),"word"],dist_min=apply(dist, 1, min))
output
       NoteID    word word_close   dist_min
    1      a1     hit        hot 0.22222222
    2      b2     hot        hot 0.00000000
    3      c3   shirt       shot 0.21666667
    4      d4    than       that 0.16666667
    5      e5 thought     though 0.04761905
    6      a1     hat       that 0.08333333
    7      b2     get        got 0.22222222
    8      c3   shirt       shot 0.21666667
    9      d4    that       that 0.00000000
    10     e5   tough     though 0.05555556
```

If you want have just in word_close the words under a certain distance threshold (in this case 0.1), you can do this:

```
output[output$dist_min>=0.1,c("word_close","dist_min")]<-NA
output
   NoteID    word word_close   dist_min
1      a1     hit       <NA>         NA
2      b2     hot        hot 0.00000000
3      c3   shirt       <NA>         NA
4      d4    than       <NA>         NA
5      e5 thought     though 0.04761905
6      a1     hat       that 0.08333333
7      b2     get       <NA>         NA
8      c3   shirt       <NA>         NA
9      d4    that       that 0.00000000
10     e5   tough     though 0.05555556
```

Comment: this looks great but are you able to explain how the scoring works? ie is this just on a 1 to 1 basis or as a comparison across the other terms? the first row above i would have thought hot and got would score the same as it would take both one change to get to hit? and also can i define what range of scoring i want to see a match for ie in the above scores of 0.1 - 0.25 would indicate near words (I'm already finding exact matches). Thanks

Comment: In this example I used Jaro–Winkler distance (method="jw"). You can find here the formula and a detailed explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance The match is between all words as you can see in table dist, after that I choose only the most close. I have added in the answer a column with the minimum distance in the output [which is between 0 'perfect match' and 1 'maximum distance']

Comment: About the scores, I will add some code rows in the answer

Comment: thats great. thanks for the quick response. updated work great and i can tune the 'flag score' as needed